# SQL Nested Aggregation

Tags: sql

I am working with SQL Language.

I have a table named parta. I want to count the fields  40b1 and  40b2 and find the sum of this. My query is here.

```
       select
         count(40b1) as 40b1,
         count(40b2) as 40b2,
         sum(count(40b1) + count(40b2) ) as sum,
         code/100 as code 
      from     parta 
      where  40b1=true and mandays>=1000
      group by code/100 ;
```

Expected output

```
       40b1     40b2   sum   code verticalsum
        5        5      10    20   7
        2        2       4     21  7
```

How it done? Please help.

For getting this verticalsum column, what query can I use?

Comment: What is the output you get from your query? What are the data in your `table`

Comment: Actually, the above mentioned code does't work. It shows the error like ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested

Comment: can you make an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: @Rose Can you clean up your SQL query in the question?  Where is `code` coming from?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Database: PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `SUM()` the `COUNT()`'s. Just add them together.

```
select count(40b1) as 40b1,
       count(40b2) as 40b2,
       count(40b1) + count(40b2) as sum,
       code/100 as code 
from     parta 
where  40b1=true and mandays>=1000
group by code/100 ;
```

Comment: @ Mike. It works fine. I also want the vertical sum of each column of resultant table. how it is possible?

Comment: Instead of adding the counts add the sums: `SUM(col1) + SUM(col2)`

Comment: Tbh it should be a separate post since it is a separate question. Questions on SO should be specific so they can have specific answers. But from looking at your edit you just want to sum one of the columns. Your code only makes sense if the two columns you're aggregating on contain nulls anyway otherwise the counts will always be the same.

Comment: Also it's a good idea to tag with the specific SQL server you're using (ms sql, mysql, oracle) unless you're after pure ANSI SQL answers since the can be vendor specific solutions that perform better.